# Pandas Data Cleaning

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pdf

So I'm reading tables from a PDF into a pandas dataframe, but I'm still pretty new to pandas, and it is pretty daunting going through the documentation. I'm sure there is a fairly easy way to do what I need to, but I just don't know how.

```
          0                    1           2        3                4                5       6       7                      8              9        10               11          12   13
0        NaN                 col0        col1     col2             col3             col4    col5    col6                   col7           col8     col9            col10       col11  NaN
1        NaN             Location        Date      NaN              NaN              NaN     NaN     NaN                    NaN            NaN      NaN              NaN         NaN  NaN
2        NaN             measure1         1**     40**             30**             20**      20  0.02**                    3**           10**      5**            100**        15**  NaN
3        NaN             measure2         100      400              300              200     200       2                    300            100       50            1,000         150  NaN
4        NaN            location1   1/15/1994     5900            28000             7600   25000     150                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
5        NaN                  NaN   3/16/1994     4900            12000             4400   11000      60                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
6        NaN                  NaN    1/4/1995        1                1                1       1       8                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
7        NaN                  NaN   4/12/2004     8400            34000             4600   17000   <1000                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
8        NaN                  NaN   7/28/2008     3200            15400             4430   17100  172  I                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
9        NaN                  NaN   5/19/2011     2000            11000             2500    9200  0.2  1                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
10       NaN                  NaN    8/6/2013     2700            20000             5300   20000    2  6                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
11       NaN                  NaN  11/13/2013     2600            14000             5400   20000  0.1  3                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
12       NaN                  NaN    2/5/2014     3200            19000             6400   25000   18  0                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
13       NaN                  NaN    5/7/2014     2000            15000             4100   16000   22  0                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
14       NaN                  NaN  12/18/2014     2500            32000             5200   20000    8  8                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
15       NaN                  NaN    6/4/2015     1700            15000             5200   21000   44  0                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
16       NaN                  NaN   1/20/2017     1400           15,000            6,300  21,000    1  2                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
17       NaN            location2   1/15/1994      210              290               39     180      69                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
18       NaN                  NaN   3/24/1994     1500            12000             4100   18000  400  0                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
19       NaN                  NaN    1/4/1995        1                1                1       1       8                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
20       NaN                  NaN    2/1/2000    <1000             8900             5200   58000  <10000                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
21       NaN                  NaN   4/12/2004     <5.0               42               78     540     150                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
22       NaN                  NaN   7/28/2008     23.3             27.9               28     409    9.34                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
23       NaN                  NaN   5/19/2011      1.8               12               22     170  0.2  1                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
24       NaN                  NaN    8/6/2013      4.3               23               71     590  0.1  3                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
25       NaN                  NaN   1/19/2017   0.21 I           0.26 I              7.7      42  0.2  4                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
26       NaN            location3   3/21/1994       <1               <1               <1      <1      <8                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---  ---
27  2/1/2000                   <1          <1       <1               <2              <10     ---     ---                    ---            ---      ---              ---         NaN  NaN
```

So there are three major problems that I need to deal with.

First: The last row somehow is not aligned with the others. I need to shift all the values in the lost row over two columns to the right, so the dates are lined up. This also means that first column shouldn't exist.

Second: Due to the dumb way these tables are set up in the PDF some other things got messed up. The Date column should just be dates. I need to somehow shift all of the rows in the Date column that don't say 'Date' or have a date down one column.

Last: The location NaNs. All of the NaN values under each location actually pertain to the same location, so I need to fill those in somehow.

So my desired output would look more like this...

```
          0                 1           2        3                4                5       6       7                      8              9        10               11          12      13
0       
1                     Location        Date     col1             col2             col3    col4    col5                   col6           col7     col8             col9       col10    col11
2                     measure1         NaN      1**             40**             30**    20**      20                 0.02**            3**     10**              5**       100**     15**
3                     measure2         NaN      100              400              300     200     200                      2            300      100               50       1,000     150
4                    location1   1/15/1994     5900            28000             7600   25000     150                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
5                    location1   3/16/1994     4900            12000             4400   11000      60                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
6                    location1    1/4/1995        1                1                1       1       8                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
7                    location1   4/12/2004     8400            34000             4600   17000   <1000                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
8                    location1   7/28/2008     3200            15400             4430   17100  172  I                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
9                    location1   5/19/2011     2000            11000             2500    9200  0.2  1                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
10                   location1    8/6/2013     2700            20000             5300   20000    2  6                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
11                   location1  11/13/2013     2600            14000             5400   20000  0.1  3                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
12                   location1    2/5/2014     3200            19000             6400   25000   18  0                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
13                   location1    5/7/2014     2000            15000             4100   16000   22  0                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
14                   location1  12/18/2014     2500            32000             5200   20000    8  8                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
15                   location1    6/4/2015     1700            15000             5200   21000   44  0                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
16                   location1   1/20/2017     1400           15,000            6,300  21,000    1  2                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
17                   location2   1/15/1994      210              290               39     180      69                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
18                   location2   3/24/1994     1500            12000             4100   18000  400  0                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
19                   location2    1/4/1995        1                1                1       1       8                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
20                   location2    2/1/2000    <1000             8900             5200   58000  <10000                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
21                   location2   4/12/2004     <5.0               42               78     540     150                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
22                   location2   7/28/2008     23.3             27.9               28     409    9.34                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
23                   location2   5/19/2011      1.8               12               22     170  0.2  1                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
24                   location2    8/6/2013      4.3               23               71     590  0.1  3                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
25                   location2   1/19/2017   0.21 I           0.26 I              7.7      42  0.2  4                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
26                   location3   3/21/1994       <1               <1               <1      <1      <8                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
27                   location3    2/1/2000       <1               <1               <1      <2     <10                    ---            ---      ---              ---         ---     ---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first point, you can try this:

```
df = df.T
df.iloc[:,-1] = df.iloc[:,-1].shift(1)
df = df.T
df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
```

For the last point:

```
df['1'] = df['1'].ffill()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, ffill() worked magically. As for the other two points I got them working by transposing the dataframe with df.T and using shift() on the columns. I had no idea that slicing notation worked on dataframes.

Comment: just shift with axis=1. No need to transpose.

Comment: @Nick You are welcome! Please consider to upvote and accept the answer :)